# Uninsalling libiconv (which installed manually and not using yum)

Tags: linux, centos

I installed libiconv in my CentOS manually using ./configure and make.

Now this library is conflicting with the same library which installed by default by EasyApache tools of cPanel/WHM and cPanel support staff are telling me I should uninstall the libiconv library which I installed manually.

How can I uninstall softwares which I installed manually in CentOs or generally in Linux. I know if I have been installed l libiconv using a tool like yum, uninstall was easy, but what when I installed it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier that I thought. If you installed the software using make command, you can easily uninstall it completely by using "**make uninstall**".

It will remove everything and is provided by the library developer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a `--prefix` when configuring, by default, the binaries are installed to `/usr/local/bin`, the libraries are installed to `/usr/local/lib`, ... So, do a quick search with:

```
# find /usr/local -name '*iconv*'
```

Verify it is the version which you compiled and really uninstall with:

```
# find /usr/local/ -name '*iconv*' -exec rm -f '{}' \;
```